# Query Access Table by a column from another Table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am a definite beginner with anything beyond the basics of Access. I'm having an issue figuring a way to Query a Table with fields from another Table.  I have Two tables in Access, one has any Invoice with an open balance.  The other has a list of invoices where the invoices need to be adjusted.  I'm going to run a program that adjusts these invoices, so Ideally the invoices in table 2 will in table 1 today and will be gone tomorrow.  Is there a way to query table 1 by all the invoices in table 2 so I can make sure that they are all off table 1 tomorrow?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: This question is not very clear. Please include sample data with the respective table headings.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2
ON T1.Invoice = T2.Invoice
```

This will give you all the info from Table1 for every invoice in Table2, as long as the invoice exists in both tables.  If, for any reason, there is an invoice in Table2 that is not in Table1, it will not show up in this query.